# Обращение из класса к форме

Tags: c#

Ох, думаю, и надоели вам такие вопросы, которыми задаётся каждый написавший Hello World.

Значит есть одна форма Form1, есть класс Horse. В классе Horse есть метод, который должен бы в цикле (x++) задавать этот самый x как текст объекта label1 на форме. Но как реализовать доступ к объектам формы, а так же их свойствам, мне непонятно.

```
public static void Why()
    {

        int x = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            x++;
            //Вот тут я не знаю, как правильно выполнить операцию типа следующей:
          //Form1.label1.Text = x.toString();

        }
```

Гугл насиловал, самоучители читал, на форумах искал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно внутри класса формы создать метод, возвращающий экземпляр этой самой формы, а, соответственно, всех ее UI потомков.

Но если из стороннего класса **Horse** планируется иметь дело лишь с одним UI-компонентом( в данном случае, это Label ), достаточно создать метод внутри формы, возвращающий этот лэйбл. А еще лучше метод, который не возвращает, а устанавливает значение в компонент Label. Сеттер.

---

Конкретных вариантов решения проблемы довольно много. Лучший - это превратить( обернуть ) класс нужной формы в **[синглтон](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))**. 
Вот пример, демонстрирующий, как можно решить вашу задачу с использованием так называемого half-singleton( "полусинглтон" ):

```
// класс основной формы
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    // статичный экземляр. Half-Singleton.
    public static MyForm myForm = null;

    ...

    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myForm = this;

        new Horse().main();  // вызов метода для проверки корректной работы
       }

    ...

    public void setValue(String newValue)
    {
        this.mylabel1.Text = newValue;
    }

}

// любой сторонний класс
class Horse
{
    // метод для тестирования функционала
    public void main()
    {
       if(MyForm.myForm != null)
       MyForm.myForm.setValue("My New Value");
    }
}
```

А вообще все действия с компонентами формы должны выполняться внутри класса этой формы. Эта инкапсуляция способствует созданию красивого и грамотно оформленного кода.

Comment: Это примитивная задача просто для получения общего представления.
Если мне нужно будет изменить 20 label'ов, то тут уже методами не отделаться. Расскажите, пожалуйста, подробнее о методе, возвращающем экземпляр. 

P.S. даже если я создаю метод public метод в Form1, я не могу вызвать его из класса. Ето норма?

Comment: Дополнил ответ

Comment: >public static Form1 Form1 = null;
Ошибка - имена членов не могут совпадать с типами, в которые они входят.

Comment: @312312, жесть..вы шутите?

обратите внимание на **РеГиСтР** типа и названия переменной в моём варианте. Сделайте выводы.

Comment: Да, тут виноват.
Дальше тут ещё такой вопрос:
  
>if(Forma.myForm != null)
Что ещё за forma?

Comment: Чтобы не создавать нового вопроса, усложню текущий, пожалуй.

Есть Form1, класс Horse и класс Program.
В классе Program создаётся второй поток и запускает цикл из класса Horse. 
Система ругается, что я пытаюсь получить доступ к объекту, который был создан в другом потоке. Как быть?

    //Program
    Thread thr = new Thread(MyThreadFunction);
    thr.Start();
    static void MyThreadFunction()
    {        
    Horse.Why();
    }
    //Horse.Why
    int x = 0;
    while (true)
    {
    if (Form1.form1 != null)
    {
    Form1.form1.dbg.Text = x.ToString();
                }
            }

Comment: this.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    if (Form1.form1 != null)
                    {
                        Form1.form1.dbg.Text = x.ToString();
                    }
                }));

Только неправильно это - дергать форму в цикле без задержки, форма виснуть будет. Реализуйте паттерн Producer/Consumer: http://hashcode.ru/research/221526/%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-producer-consumer-pattern